# Is Order and Degree of Recurrence Relation implies the same thing?

Tags: recurrence-relations

I got confused in a very basic concept while reading **Kenneth H Rosen's** Discrete Mathematics

[image: Kenneth H Rosen]
When I searched that on internet I get more confused

**I got** [image: https://math.berkeley.edu/~arash/55/8_2.pdf]

**from** [**https://math.berkeley.edu/~arash/55/8_2.pdf**](https://math.berkeley.edu/~arash/55/8_2.pdf)

**And this** [image: **https://www.tutorialspoint.com/discrete_mathematics/discrete_mathematics_recurrence_relation.htm**]

**from**
 [**https://www.tutorialspoint.com/discrete_mathematics/discrete_mathematics_recurrence_relation.htm**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/discrete_mathematics/discrete_mathematics_recurrence_relation.htm)

**Is Order and Degree of Recurrence Relation implies the same thing?**

Comment: And the question is… ?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos i want to know Is Order and Degree of Recurrence Relation implies the same thing?

Comment: Yes, they mean the same thing.

Comment: @GerryMyerson But In general both have different meaning?

Comment: What do you mean by "in general"? In group theory, the order of a group is not the same thing as the degree of a group.